# How to read data in "Debian control file" (DCF) format?

Tags: r, dataframe

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ruJKO-C1_PTLtulyPWsvoufJB6yX7vdx/view?usp=sharing)

Please advice on the best way to read this type of data into a data frame in R.

Using `read.table("Software.txt")` only gives the error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
line 1 did not have 6 elements.
```

Furthermore, this data (Amazon dataset) is not in the traditional rows and columns format, so would appreciate any help on that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your data appears to be in the same "Debian control file" (DCF) format that's used to store package metadata. The correct import function for such data is

```
read.dcf("Software.txt")
```

Check out the `?read.dcf` help page for more info.

Comment: Great +1, at least OP can use my answer to clean the data a little further.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution based on `readLines`.

```
r1 <- readLines('~/Downloads/Software.txt')  ## read raw text
r2 <- r1[r1 != '']  ## remove blank elements, realize repeats every 10th
r3 <- strsplit(r2, ': ')  ## split at `: `
## remove part before `: ` and make matrix with 10 rows
r4 <- matrix(sapply(r3, `[`, 2), 10, dimnames=list(sapply(r3[1:10], `[`, 1), NULL))  
r5 <- as.data.frame(t(r4))  ## transpose and coerce to df
r6 <- setNames(r5, make.names(names(r5)))  ## names
r6[r6 == 'unknown'] <- NA  ## generate NA's 
r7 <- type.convert(r6, as.is=TRUE)  ## convert proper classes
```

You can, of course, streamline this a little. I just wanted to show you the individual steps.

### Result

```
str(r7)  
# 'data.frame': 95084 obs. of  10 variables:
# $ product.productId : chr  "B000068VBQ" "B000068VBQ" "B000068VBQ" "B000068VBQ" ...
# $ product.title     : chr  "Fisher-Price Rescue Heroes" "Fisher-Price Rescue Heroes"  ...
# $ product.price     : num  8.88 8.88 8.88 8.88 8.88 8.88 8.88 NA NA NA ...
# $ review.userId     : chr  NA NA "A10P44U29RNOT6" NA ...
# $ review.profileName: chr  NA NA "D. Jones" NA ...
# $ review.helpfulness: chr  "11/11" "9/10" "6/6" "4/4" ...
# $ review.score      : num  2 2 1 1 4 5 1 4 5 4 ...
# $ review.time       : int  1042070400 1041552000 1126742400 1042416000 1045008000  ...
# $ review.summary    : chr  "Requires too much coordination" "You can't pick which  ...
# $ review.text       : chr  "I bought this software for my 5 year old. He has a couple ...
```